# Custom button push back

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, push, slide

I have two views which use UINavigationController. I want the second view to "slide" with animation back to the first view when I tap on a custom button. (not the original in navigationbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this on that button action,

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] - 2)] animated:YES];
```

Here `aViewController` represents the previous view controller. Similarly you can pop to any viewcontroller you want by using a similar code.

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` will take you to the root view controller.

Comment: I can't change aViewController to MasterViewController.

Comment: `MasterViewController`is my first viewcontroller... But thanks! The second code worked ;)